# Blotter package does not work when I run the code 2nd time

Tags: r, quantitative-finance, quantstrat

I was playing with quanstrat code from Guy Yollin's notes. The sample code is provided below:

```
library(quantstrat)
library(blotter)

search()
currency("USD")
stock("SPY", currency = "USD", multiplier = 1)

ls(envir = FinancialInstrument:::.instrument)

ls(all=T)

initDate <- '1997-12-31'
startDate <- '1998-01-01'
endDate <- '2014-06-30'
initEq <- 1e6

Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC")

options("getSymbols.yahoo.warning"=FALSE)

getSymbols('SPY', from = startDate, to = endDate, index.class = "POSIXct", adjust = T)

SPY$SMA10m <- SMA(Cl(SPY), 10)

#rm.strat(qs.strategy)

qs.strategy <- "qsFaber"

initPortf(qs.strategy, 'SPY', initDate = initDate)
```

When I ran it first time, I had no issues. When I ran it second time without modifying anything, I got the error message below:

> Error in exists(paste("portfolio", name, sep = "."), envir = .blotter,  : 
>     object '.blotter' not found

I did the `search()` and the > "package:blotter" appeared. I have to restart RStudio in order to get this working. I am getting the same error every second time I run this code.

Any solutions or suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Hey again blackknight316,

I answered another one of your questions this morning and it seems you have questions related to getting started with [quantstrat](/questions/tagged/quantstrat) in general. Similar to that one, It seems that when trying to cut, paste, and recreate the code examples of others, you maybe using arguments that may not be relevant to your script.

In addition, the environment is likely getting cluttered with examples that have overlapping objects, which could be leading to some inconsistent behavior. But there is not enough information in the post to know if that is happening.

Might I suggest checking out the excellent quantstrat intro course at datacamp.com?

https://www.datacamp.com/courses/financial-trading-in-r

It walks one through an entire strategy with videos and examples from start to finish and discusses all the main functions, what their arguments do, and will give you a working example.

Good luck,

Justin

[r](/questions/tagged/r)

Comment: Hey Justin,
Thanks for answering this question. I havent had a chance to test the other suggestion you made. I will do that once I get home.

I did not think about datacamp at all. I really appreciate you for suggesting me this. I bet this will give me a great start!

Once again. Thank you very much!

Comment: Justin, I tried clearing the workspace using rm(list = ls()). Its working fine now!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix for this issue is to simply manually create the required environments within your script. If you're removing all global variables at the top of your script, you can insert the following code:

```
rm(list = ls(all.names = T))
.blotter <- new.env()
.strategy <- new.env()
```

Note, you must keep the `.blotter` and `.strategy` names as these are the default names used by the blotter and quantstrat packages, respectively.